# Laravel socialite and SPA Loging

Tags: oauth-2.0, vue.js, facebook-login, laravel-socialite

I'm using `vue.js` and `laravel` and `vue-authenticate` whose documentation can be find [here](https://github.com/dgrubelic/vue-authenticate).

My frontend is running on `localhost:8080` the backend on `127.0.0.1:8000`

#### vue-authenticate config

```
Vue.use(VueAuthenticate, {
  baseUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000', // Your API domain

  providers: {
    facebook: {
      clientId: '123456789',
      redirectUri: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/facebook/callback', // Your client app URL
      scope: ['email', 'rsvp_event', 'public_profile', 'user_events']
    }
  }
});
```

#### Issue

When I click to log myself with `Facebook` I have this error

> Client error: `POST
>   https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/oauth/access_token` resulted in a `400
>   Bad Request` response: {"error":{"message":"Error validating
>   verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to
>   the one you (truncated...)

The URL looks like this :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/facebook/callback?code=AQCio_tQpGgfBUKrdBRqIFDMS9NJvaFXX4hhnyFhKylIoTmU27ciMHBZiojdJT5XA2pApaPsoRO3ocokWrDx-TEBTSOmWQErkcmbOEi6fUYUPtlfJfiYw-49NyKYEDq63akgEqDI2r2FeBrw2Wo8IjlchNZ7F_IcAIyJjstVYShCZAK3Beu_rNEPG-1M6wvLHqXbe2dhRQcW9TeE2dxtewK-MPEb3ffmmoX5bK9uyZrF-TTH4tpsOKI2S6HPpDy2wSasUcXCtdMJfV3TLFuFlq1H3pgza6nyvhy8Ln1OQYbRTT30uBaZWnUt7R3JQsfAxzM#_=_
```

#### Questions

What should I do to fix this issue ?

Also I have to say I am a bit confused with the callback functions and so on. Am I calling the right function at the right moment ?

#### Laravel routes

```
Route::get('auth/facebook', 'SocialAuthController@redirectToProviderApi');
Route::get('facebook/callback', 'SocialAuthController@handleProviderCallbackAPI');
```

#### Functions

```
 public function redirectToProviderApi()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('facebook')
            ->scopes(['rsvp_event', 'public_profile', 'user_events'])
            ->stateless()->redirect();
    }

    public function handleProviderCallbackAPI (Request $request) {

        $name = 'facebook';
        if ($request->has('redirectUri')) {
            config()->set("services.{$name}.redirect", $request->get('redirectUri'));
        }


        $provider = Socialite::driver($name);

        $provider->stateless();

        // Step 1 + 2
        $profile = $provider->user();
        $user = $service->createOrGetUser($profile);
        return response()->json(['token' => $this->createToken($user)]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Facebook API `redirect_uri` must be the same to the one that you are using

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/facebook/callback
```